# Typo3 7 redirect to one page

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have created my own extension with extbase and need some help. I've added my plugin in the backend and can already see the output in the frontend. When using both my searchbar and output action together, everything is working properly.

My problem is that I want to split my searchbar and output action. I want my searchbar be in every page on the website. Using my searchbar should reload the page with the searchbar and the output that matches the search parameters. I already have my searchbar in the header, but the result is also in the header.

I've implemented my searchbar through Typoscript!

Comment: That was the other thing I wanted to hint in my switchabeContollerAction answer, but can't find the time to do so right now. You're better off splitting these into two seperate plugins - otherwise the link parameters will always influence both output plugins.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any reference where I can find how to do this?

Comment: Yes, I've added an answer.

Comment: Thanks it works. I have another problem, when I am submitting, my args are empty for my searchbar, my output is OK. Is there a way to get my args for the searchbar to fill the input fields?

Comment: Yes. You've got to read the arguments of that plugin to do so. Thers an old article on buzz that explains that process. https://buzz.typo3.org/teams/extbase/article/howto-share-variables-between-extension-plugins/

Comment: Thanks good example! Btw. t3lib_div:: is obsolete use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::

Comment: Yes, the buzz article is somewhat outdated. I think I'll put some more info into my answer as soon as I find the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate plugin for the search bar. That way, link arguments for your list and show actions won't influence the search bar. In your ext_localconf.php, add another `configurePlugin()` call:

```
// Search bar
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Searchbar',
    array(
        'Controller' => 'search',
    ),
    array(
    )
);
```

Then, reconfigure your typoscript setup to include this plugin instead.

You then need to make sure that the parameters from the search bar end up as arguments for the other plugin. There's a `pluginName` property in the `<f:form>` ViewHelper that lets you do that.